# XPath access to child nodes of node within SVG

Tags: xpath

Is it possible to access to the elements inside of a `<g>` tag having a class using XPath?

I access the class with:

```
/*[contains(@class, 'highcharts-markers highcharts-tracker')]
```

but I do not know how access its children.

```
<g class="highcharts-markers highcharts-tracker" visibility="visible" zIndex="1" transform="translate(40,44) scale(1 1)" clip-path="none" style="">
  <path fill="#00285e" d="M 330 6.34 C 332.66 6.341 332.66 10.34 330 10.34 C 327.33 10.34 327.336 6.34 330 6.34 Z" stroke-width="1"/>
  <path fill="#00285e" d="M 319 105.66 C 321.664 105.66 321.664 109.66 319 109.66 C 316.336 109.66 316.336 105.66 319 105.66 Z" stroke-width="1"/>
  <path fill="#00285e" d="M 308 55.48 C 310.664 55.48 310.664 59.48 308 59.48 C 305.336 59.48 305.336 55.48 308 55.48 Z" stroke-width="1"/>
</g>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a step `/*[contains(@class, 'highcharts-markers highcharts-tracker')]/*` to access all child elements. And to access a certain element you can add a predicate, e.g. `/*[contains(@class, 'highcharts-markers highcharts-tracker')]/*[1]` gives you the first child element. To access an attribute, you can add a further step, e.g. `/*[contains(@class, 'highcharts-markers highcharts-tracker')]/*[1]/@fill` gives you the `fill` attribute of the first child element.

Comment: @JuanReinaPascual, I have edited the answer with some more examples, but you should definitely start with an XPath tutorial.